# ruby on rails: average numeric values from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm allowing users to insert numberic values into database, and I can output them through an each loop. But is there a way to just output the average value? Like say, if user is reviewing this person (only 1-5 values), I would want to output only the average instead of

```
<% @ratings.each do |r| %>
  <%= r.rating %>
<% end %>
```

This displays all the records. How do I only display the average (which should also need the total of reviews this user has right)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of going about this. For instance, you could potentially abstract this logic into a custom helper. The approach I would take is to bring this logic into the model and create a convenience method on the `User` model itself:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :ratings

    def average_rating
        ratings_array = ratings.map(&:rating)
        ratings_array.inject{ |sum, el| sum + el }.to_f
    end
end
```

Then, if your view, you'd access ratings like so:

```
<%= @user.ratings %>
```

UPDATE:

If you're inclined to use a view helper, something like this would work:

```
# app/helpers/ratings_helper.rb
module RatingsHelper
    def average_rating(ratings)
        ratings_array = ratings.map(&:rating)
        ratings_array.inject{|sum, el| sum + el}.to_f       
    end

end
```

In your view, you'd access the average by passing in the ratings to calculate the average of:

```
<%= average_rating(@user.ratings) %>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

**Wow**. There's a native ActiveRecord function called [`average()`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-average) that will calculate the average value of a given column *with a single line of code*:

```
<%= @user.ratings.average('rating') %>
```

I believe this function operates on the database level. If so, using this method would almost certainly generate the lowest overhead of any of the solutions listed.

Answer (score 1):

its better to use some caching for the average rating. For example

```
user has_many ratings
```

and `rating belongs_to :user`

Then in rating model you may have a after_save call_back to save average ratings to its user. To achieve this you have to have average_ratings column in post model.

And in rating.rb:

```
after_save :update_average_ratings

private

def update_average_ratings
  average_ratings = self.user.ratings.collect(&:rating).sum / self.user.ratings.count
 user.update_attributes(average_ratings: average_ratings)

end
```

It will be very efficient and you can call @user.average_ratings when you need that.

Hope that helps